# According to Penrose, Weyl Tensor=0 is the start/end of the Universe. Must it =0?

Tags: universe, big-bang

If I understand Roger Penrose's theory, as the Universe expands and cools, matter is consumed by black holes. Eventually the black holes collide and evaporate so that there is only energy and the Weyl tensor (which relates to matter) heads to zero.  He argues at zero, there is no effective space-time (my paraphrase) and the Universe 'reboots', turning that remaining energy into a new Big Bang.  If this is correct-ish framing of his theory, (in a crude, layman's way) is there a lower bound for the Weyl tensor to allow a 'reboot'? 
If there is such a non-zero value I presume that such a lower bound for Weyl tensor would be passed from a 'previous universe' and be part of the initial state the 'next universe'.
Have I mangled Penroses's theory? If not, could the low Weyl tensor that would exist at T=0, explain any of the symmetry or fundamental constants that we observe in our Universe (Planks, fine structure etc)?